# Can you do pattern matching on the type-level in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, algebraic-data-types

Basically, what I want is a function that takes a function type (a -> b -> c -> ...), and returns a list of all the right-subset types of that function type, for example, lets call this function f:

```
x = f (a -> b -> c)

x
> [a -> b -> c, b -> c, c]
```

And this should work for both polymorphic types, as in my example, and on concrete function types.

This would be relatively straightforward if you could pattern match on the type-level with function types like so:

```
g (x -> xs) = xs
g (x) = x
```

used as a utility function for the construction of f above, and pattern matching over function types sort of like one would pattern match over a list.

Comment: Do you really want a type-level function? What would you do wiith it?

Comment: Well, to be honest, some type-level voodoo that probably wouldn't work in Haskell because of it's lack of untagged sum types.

As an end goal, I basically want a way to construct a sum type out of all possible right subsets of a function type. The utility of that relates to my attempt at simplifying parts of Applicative Universal Grammar. This is all very experimental.

Comment: Basically, thinking of words as functions (as is done in AUG), I want a type that allows for more or less specification, allowing for either n-ary functions (words or phrases that have unspecified modifiers), a concrete phrase (nullary function), or anywhere in-between represented as partially applied functions, so I want a type to allow for all of those cases.

Comment: @Sintrastes I added something that might help with the untagged sum type thing.

Comment: Although, I suspect it would be a lot easier to make an EDSL than to directly manipulate Haskell function types for this.

Comment: Thanks for all the info David! Just for reference, I have tried things like using Maybes in my previous endeavors with implementing natural language grammars in Haskell, (e.a. things like data VP = VP Verb (Maybe Adverb)) but that can get ugly. There might be a better way that what I want to do right now as well, I'm just starting to research AUG, so I'm basically experimenting for experimentation's sake right now, seeing how well different strategies work.

Comment: @Sintrastes Hmm, I'm not totally sure how to design something like that without looking into it a little more, but it might be a good idea to look into GADTs and phantom types as well (those two things go together nicely). It might be a good way to avoid needing powerful type level functions. GADTs can define a statically type-checked EDSL (among other things).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Closed type families are what you're looking for:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
type family F a where
    F (x -> xs) = xs
    F x         = x
```

To fully answer your question, we need DataKinds to get type-level lists too:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, TypeOperators, DataKinds #-}

type family F a :: [*] where
    F (x -> xs) = (x -> xs) ': (F xs)
    F x         = '[x]
```

The single quote indicates that we are using those (list) constructors at a type level.

We can see that this gives the expected result with the `:kind!` command in GHCi

```
λ> :kind! F (Int -> Float -> Double)
F (Int -> Float -> Double) :: [*]
= '[Int -> Float -> Double, Float -> Double, Double]
```

Note that the return kind of `F` is `[*]`. This means that in order to use these results, you will need to extract them from the list in some way. The only kind that has types that are inhabited is `*` (well, and `#`).

### Untagged sum types

Regarding the full context:
You might be able to make something like an untagged sum type by making an `Elem` type family using the type level `(==)` and `(||)` from `Data.Type.Equality` and `Data.Type.Bool` respectively.